# You're not allowed to use the command even tho my friend has perms

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was coding and need help with this
Here's my code

```js
const DiscordCommand = require("../../contracts/DiscordCommand");
const admins = ["445952068621041664", "398909948194586634"];
class OverrideCommand extends DiscordCommand {
  onCommand(message) {
    if (admins.includes(message.author.id)) {
      let args = this.getArgs(message).join(" ");

      if (args.length == 0) {
        return message.reply(`No command specified`);
      }

      this.sendMinecraftMessage(`/${args}`);

      message.reply(`\`/${args}\` has been executed`);
    } else message.reply(`You dont have permissions to use this command!`);
  }
}
module.exports = OverrideCommand;
```

What I am trying to do here is making that 2 people can execute the command "+override" as in the const admins with 2 id's the first one is mine and the 2nd is my friends when I try to use the command it works fine but when my friend executes it, it gives me this error

````
/app/src/discord/commands/OverrideCommand.js:3
const admins = ['445952068621041664', '398909948194586634\]
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18) ```
````

Would really appreciate if someone could help me with this I am very new to coding

Edit: The problem has changed and its not lettin my friend use the command even tho the array admins has his id innit url to the pic (just if needed) https://prnt.sc/10uf39r

Comment: Tye error message makes it seem like it is has a typo

Comment: Should this not end in a single quote instead of a backslash..? '398909948194586634\ ... Just looks like invalid json.

Comment: thats what it says in the logs even tho its correct in my code it gives that in my logs

Comment: Are you certain that the code snippet you posted is from `/app/src/discord/commands/OverrideCommand.js`?

Comment: yes it is......

Comment: This is just a very basic syntax error. This post will not help anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admins array is invalid json

```
['445952068621041664', '398909948194586634\]
```

Should be

```
['445952068621041664', '398909948194586634']
```

Comment: I did that in this code 
the first id is mine 2nd of another friend
const admins = ['445952068621041664','408507536791044096']
but it still says You're not allowed to use the command even tho the id here is my friends

Comment: Ok. So maybe this was correct but maybe the problem has changed from the initial post. Maybe update the question with the problem?

Comment: This is a new error btw the old one is gone the 2nd id here is my friends but its still saying You're not allowed to use this command here's the url of the pic if wanted [link](https://prnt.sc/10uf39r)

Comment: @epicgamer69 if the specific error you initially posted about is resolved here, mark this answer with the checkmark. If you are now encountering a new problem, create a new question focused on that new problem. That's how things tend to work here - this process creates a very focused workflow!

Comment: I agree with @Gershy. That rule of thumb / convention seems clearer and easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking `if` that the author of the message is `ID` or `ID`

```
if(message.author.id != ID || message.author.id != ID){
  message.reply(`You dont have permissions to use this command!`)
}
```